# What options do we have to get a year long visa to the Schengen States as US citizens?

Tags: immigration, schengen

We are retired, financially blessed, mid 50's and wanting to purchase a motorhome for our journey. We have a real estate corp. (S type) in the US. We have looked through the internet and not found any direct methods. D type National Visa would be perfect but we don't know how to pretest our application before sending it in. Would extended visa in Italy (for example) allow us to travel more in the other Schengen States or just stay in Italy until our next 90 days of 180 open up? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: If you get such a visa for Italy, you'd be limited strictly speaking, to 90 days out of every 180 for all the other Schengen countries, but in practice there's no way to enforce this systematically.  I'm not sure whether Italy actually grants such a visa, but I know that France does.

Comment: Thanks phoog for the comment. France would be another option. We wanted a centralize extension country so if we "happened" to stray out into another country for a weekend or so the explanation/excuse would be more believable.            We also just mined some information on the Dutch American Friendship Treaty - another possible but expensive (4,500) without the application fees. Any experience with that?

Comment: This question was from a few years ago, though yesterday I just read an article about how a couple of US retirees managed to get long-term visas to live in Greece https://www.marketwatch.com/story/we-retired-to-athens-without-speaking-greek-heres-how-we-got-the-easy-travel-and-affordable-life-we-wanted-11606849562 Not sure if it's a similar situation though since that's not exactly a travel visa.

Answer (score 1):

France certainly have a visa called as long sejour (tourist). But from fresh experience (and I was being advised by a top-notch lawyer-emigration agent), I would suggest to not rely on it- its rarely given, and Embassy can find trivial reasons to refuse it. Not worth of time, and hassle.

Spain has got similar visa, and if you can really afford it, investing there could get you this visa with ease. You might have to check the duration of your stay against the investment though.